# MFC can't redraw CTabCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc

On my MFC form (with tabcontrl controls and ok/cancel button) , I only use the Onresize event(not use ON_WM_ERASEBKGND ,..) as follows:

```
 CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
 m_cTab.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, cx, cy - 36, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    
m_cTab.Invalidate();
int w, h; GetDlgItem(ID_MultiplotOk)->GetWindowRect(&rec);
GetDlgItem(ID_Ok)->SetWindowPos(NULL, cx - 180, cy - 30, rec.Width(), rec.Height(),  SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
GetDlgItem(ID_Cancel)->SetWindowPos(NULL, cx - 90, cy - 30, rec.Width(), rec.Height(),  SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
this->Invalidate();
this->UpdateWindow();
```

the code works ok, however the tabcontrol is not redrawn as expected.

Did I miss the thing?

[image]

Comment: This looks like you aren't properly resizing the tab control contents to fit inside the tab control's display area.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IInspectable!, after many fixes, that control finally fit as I expected .